can I handle server side rendering on button click in angular 17 ssr?
I am new to angular ssr.
I am working on a blogging website, where about 10 blogs are displayed on a single page. I load next 10 blogs on click of a button in angular v17 with ssr.
when i build the app, only first page is pre-rendered (i.e. rendered on the server side).
But when I click the button to load next page, the page is rendered on client side and not on server side.
Is there any way where I can render the page on server side when i click the button?

please share the minimal reproducible code

ssr makes sense only for the very first render of the initial page. other points of time not only won't work, but they don't make any sense
